# Idiomatic way in RxJS to calculate the maximum of a stream of values

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs

Calculating the maximum of a fixed stream is straightforward, for example:

```
var source = Rx.Observable.from([1,3,5,7,9,2,4,6,8]).max();
```

However this only generates one value (9 in this case).

I would like to generate a sequence of maximum values so far, until the Observable produces a new maximum value. So the output would be something like [1, 3, 5, 7, 9].

My idea so far has been to merge the output stream with maximum values, with the input stream (using [combineLatest](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/combinelatest.md)) and compare the two values. However this seems to be more complicated to me than it should be.

Comment: Never mind: I completely overlooked the scan operator in RxJS. Will close/delete this question.

Comment: I think you shouldn't close the question, somebody might have overlooked scan too. Besides, you need `distinctUntilChanged` after `scan` to produce that output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `scan` function in that way :

```
function max(a,b) {return (a>b ? a : b}

var max$ = source$.scan(max,0);
```

[Scan](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/scan.md) allows you to have a stream which follows a relation of the type `On+1 = f(In+1, Sn)` where `In` is the nth input of the source stream, `On` would be the nth output, and `Sn` would be a value accumulated over the sequence (similar to `reduce` operator for arrays).